# How to use template classes in main function

Tags: c++, class, templates, program-entry-point

I need to use a template class in my main function. This is because I am referencing a template class inside my main function. For example:

```
LinkedListInterface<T>  * linkedList = new LinkedListInterface<T>*;
```

So I tried putting the template declaration above "int main()"

```
template<typename T>
int main()
```

But then I got the linking error because it no longer recognized this as a main function. I tried some work arounds, like making a function that did everything, but then that function had to be a template class, so I still couldn't call it from main. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

`

Answer (score 2):

`main` cannot be a function template; it must be a function.  To use a class template within `main`, you have to instantiate the template by providing all the required template parameters with the object declaration:

```
LinkedListInterface<int> linkedList;
```

This tells the compiler to create a class from the class template `LinkedListInterface` where the first template parameter is the type `int`.  It then creates an object of that type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to template the main but I don't think that you want do that.

When you use a template you can do this:

```
LinkedListInterface<int> *linkedList = new LinkedListInterface<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is much worse problem:**

Compiler can't differentiate the template function instantiations anyway, since it can't tell the difference between `main<int>` and `main<whatever>`, since they are not part of the template function signature.

As noted by other answers, main can't be a template.